# Как обратится к методу С++?

Tags: c++, ооп, c++11

У меня есть переменна типа Figure*. Как мне обратится к методу, которого нету в Figure, но есть в AnyFigure?
AnyFigure наследуется от Figure.
method - метод который есть в AnyFigure, но нету в Figure

```
Figure* figure = new AnyFigure();
figure->method();
```

Comment: static_cast<AnyFigure*>(figure)->method() ?

Comment: Ох, нехорошее это дело, говорящее о том, что вы что-то не продумали. Раз вам нужен вызов метода потомка, значит, вам автоматом нужен экземпляр потомка - так зачем его получать через указатель на родителя? По делу - правильнее всего использовать `dynamic_cast<>`.

Comment: @HarryfromKiev dynamic_cast может вызвать ошибку компиляции - мы же не знаем полиморфный ли базовый класс Figure.

Comment: @ampawd Я же написал не "всегда использовать", а "правильнее всего", т.е. использовать именно такой класс, для которого может быть выполнена проверка времени выполнения.